# Animated movie with a group of Pegasus living by a waterfall and mountainous area

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

When I was a child, this would have been around 1990's and later, I watched an animated movie where there were a group of Pegasus living by a waterfall and mountainous area. There were both white and black Pegasus. If I am remembering it right they spoke (although I could be mistaken). Perhaps it wasn't a movie but a series of some kind?

- It isn't *Fantasia* as I have re-watched it and came back with a vehement no.
- It isn't *The Last Unicorn*.

Comment: Hi and welcome. A good start to your time here, but take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if it jogs any more memories.

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure it is not *Fantasia*, the 1940 version? It sounds a lot like that movie.

Mountains- Check.
Waterfall - Check.
Group of pegasi - Check.

Also, if it is not the pegasi but bears instead, it could be "The Little Flying Bears".

Comment: Thank you! But as I said before it isn't these two. I have triple checked and just can't seem to find it. A friend even agreed with me that it isn't Fantasia but couldn't remember what it was either.

Comment: My little pony was being shown at that time. There are talking pegasi in it. Another thing with talking flying horses is "Starla and the Jewel riders". If it is one of those, I'll edit my answer and you can accept it.

Comment: I researched both just in case, but it isn't those. I really appreciate the attempt though! Perhaps one day I will be able to figure it out.

Comment: Darn, I really hoped it was my little pony, old version. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QP_rIAkb_v8 

Back to the drawing board :)

Comment: Thank you again for trying!

Answer (score -1):

Could be Rainbow Brite and the star stealer

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This could be the right answer, but you need to provide more details so we can see.  Maybe a link to screencaps from the movie, or an entry in IMDB, and you should list how it matches the details in the question.